# how can i set jquerymobile framework dialog box custom height/width?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile in my web application, I have to open html page within dialog.
I am using code below for opening html page.

```
> <a href="chart.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop"
> data-icon="false">Open HTML Page</a>
```

Page is opening with default height and width but how can i set the custom height and width of the dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height is set by the content. To adjust the width you can override the following css class. Just be sure to put this style after the JQM stylesheet.

```
.ui-dialog-contain {
    width: 92.5%; /* Change to whatever you want */
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 10% auto 15px auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```